# $\Delta u=0$ inside the quarter circle

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Find the general solution (as a series) for $\Delta u=0$ inside the quarter circle $\left\{(r, \phi): r<2,\, 0<\phi<\dfrac{\pi}{2} \right\}$ with $u(r,0)=\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial n}\left(r, \dfrac{\pi}{2} \right)=0$.

I'm quite confused by the $\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial n}$ since I normally do questions, where it is of the form $\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial \phi}$. So even just some help on how to deal with that would be helpful.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the answer of $\textbf{Ron Gordon}$, we are to solve the problem

$\left\{\begin{array}{l l}
  \Delta u=0,\,\,r<2,\,\,0<\phi<\frac{\pi}{2}\\
  u(r,0)=0\\
  \frac{\partial u}{\partial n}(r,\frac{\pi}{2})=u_\phi(r,\frac{\pi}{2})=0
\end{array}\right.$

First note that $$\Delta u=\frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial}{\partial r}\left(r\frac{\partial u}{\partial r}\right)+\frac{1}{r^2}\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial \theta^2}=0\quad(1)$$ in polar coordinates $(r,\theta)$. Now, assume that $u(r,\theta)=R(r)\Theta(\theta)$ is a solution of the problem. By $(1)$, it follows that

$$\frac{1}{r}(rR')'\Theta+\frac{1}{r^2}\Theta''R=0 \iff \frac{r(rR')'}{R}=-\frac{\Theta''}{\Theta}=\lambda \iff \left\{\begin{array}{l l}
  \Theta''+\lambda\Theta=0\quad(2)\\
  r(rR')'-\lambda R=0\quad(3)
\end{array}\right.$$

By $(2)$ and the boundary conditions, $\Theta$ is given as the solution of the problem

$\left\{\begin{array}{l l}
  \Theta''+\lambda\Theta=0\\
  \Theta(0)=0\\
  \Theta'(\frac{\pi}{2})=0
\end{array}\right.$

Let us now consider different cases.

$\lambda<0$: The general solution of the above ODE is $\Theta(\theta)=A\cosh(\sqrt{|\lambda|}\theta)+B\sinh(\sqrt{|\lambda|}\theta)$. The first condition implies that $0=\Theta(0)=A$, so $\Theta(\theta)=B\sinh(\sqrt{|\lambda|}\theta)$ and $\Theta'(\theta)=\sqrt{|\lambda|}B\cosh(\sqrt{|\lambda|}\theta)$. The second condition implies that $0=\Theta'(\frac{\pi}{2})=\sqrt{|\lambda|}B\cosh(\sqrt{|\lambda|}\frac{\pi}{2})$, so $B=0$ and thus no non-trivial solution exists.

$\lambda=0$: The general solution of the above ODE is $\Theta(\theta)=A\theta+B$. The first condition implies that $0=\Theta(0)=B$, so $\Theta(\theta)=A\theta$ and $\Theta'(\theta)=A$. The second condition implies that $0=\Theta'(\frac{\pi}{2})=A$, so $A=0$ and thus no non-trivial solution exists.

$\lambda>0$: The general solution of the above ODE is $\Theta(\theta)=A\cos(\sqrt{\lambda}\theta)+B\sin(\sqrt{\lambda}\theta)$. The first condition implies that $0=\Theta(0)=A$, so $\Theta(\theta)=B\sin(\sqrt{\lambda}\theta)$ and $\Theta'(\theta)=\sqrt{\lambda}B\cos(\sqrt{\lambda}\theta)$. The second condition implies that $0=\Theta'(\frac{\pi}{2})=\sqrt{\lambda}B\cos(\sqrt{\lambda}\frac{\pi}{2})$, so $B=0$ or $\sqrt{\lambda}=2k+1$. Hence $\Theta_k(\theta)=\sin((2k+1)\theta)$ is a non-trivial solution for $\lambda_k=(2k+1)^2$, where $k\in\mathbb{N}^0$.

Now, we solve $(3)$ with $\lambda_k=(2k+1)^2$. It follows that

$$r^2R''+rR'-(2k+1)^2R=0 \implies R_k(r)=a_kr^{2k+1}+b_kr^{-2k-1}$$

However, since $r^{-2k-1}$ grows unboundedly large as we approach the origin, we have to choose $b_k=0$ for all $k$.

Hence the general solution to your problem is given by

$$u(r,\theta)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty R_k(r)\Theta_k(\theta)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_kr^{2k+1}\sin((2k+1)\theta)$$

The constants $\{a_k\}_{k=0}^\infty$ are arbitrary.

Answer (score 3):

Because $\phi=\pi/2$ is on the $y$-axis, $\partial u/\partial n = -\partial u/\partial x$, as the normal derivative is taken to be outward from the region.

It should be noted that

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x} = \cos{\phi} \frac{\partial}{\partial r} - \frac{\sin{\phi}}{r} \frac{\partial}{\partial \phi}$$

At $\phi=\pi/2$ this is

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x} = -\frac{1}{r} \frac{\partial}{\partial \phi}$$

so that the normal derivative being zero at $\phi=\pi/2$ is equivalent to $u_{\phi} = 0$ there.